How can I edit my tailwindcss.config.ts file in the nextjs
My tailwindcss.config.ts file is as shown below. The tailwindcss color is detected in the dashboard in the admin folder, but the color is not detected in the admin folder at login. When I make my tailwindcss.config.ts file the start of the project installation, my problem is solved. How can I fix my tailwindcss.config.ts file?
tailwindcss.config.ts
import { createThemes } from "tw-colors";
import colors from "tailwindcss/colors";

const baseColors = [
  "gray",
  "red",
  "yellow",
  "green",
  "blue",
  "indigo",
  "purple",
  "pink",
];

const shadeMapping = {
  "50": "900",
  "100": "800",
  "200": "700",
  "300": "600",
  "400": "500",
  "500": "400",
  "600": "300",
  "700": "200",
  "800": "100",
  "900": "50",
};

const generateThemeObject = (colors: any, mapping: any, invert = false) => {
  const theme: any = {};
  baseColors.forEach((color) => {
    theme[color] = {};
    Object.entries(mapping).forEach(([key, value]: any) => {
      const shadeKey = invert ? value : key;
      theme[color][key] = colors[color][shadeKey];
    });
  });
  return theme;
};

const lightTheme = generateThemeObject(colors, shadeMapping);
const darkTheme = generateThemeObject(colors, shadeMapping, true);

const themes = {
  light: {
    ...lightTheme,
    white: "#ffffff",
  },
  dark: {
    ...darkTheme,
    white: colors.gray["950"],
    black: colors.gray["50"],
  },
};

const config: Config = {
 
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
   
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
        "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  darkMode:[ "class"],
  mode: 'jit',
  plugins: [createThemes(themes)],
};

export default config;


I would not look to do this much computation in the config:

the config is going to be evaluated at build time, but dark / light mode is going to be evaluated at run time
you are basically saying 'when in dark mode, black is white, and white is black' so your component code is going to be confusing
TW will shake out unused definitions unless you explicitly include them

A couple of ways you might address this without adding this complexity to your config:

Use the dark modifier in your components where needed, like className="bg-grey-50 dark:bg-grey-900" Useful for one-off cases.

Define CSS variables that respond to a media query in a base CSS layer you explicitly import at the top of the app, and reference these in your TW config. This is a bit more involved:



in your CSS: e.g.

:root {
  --color-primary: theme(colors.grey.50);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --color-primary: theme(colors.grey.900);
  }
}

then in your config:
... // start of config
colors: {
  primary: 'var(--color-primary)'
}
... // end of config

Then your use of the color in a component is simple, and it's obvious what to expect when it renders: className="bg-primary" has the theme look up the CSS variable referenced in the theme, which is MQ-aware and computed at render time.
Check the TW docs for adding the appropriate directives to the CSS file - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-base-styles
